# How to run a specific cron job in Magento2

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

How can I run a specific cron job code in Magento2 instead of running it by group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use magerun http://n98-magerun.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands/sys.html#sys-cron-run

Regards!

Comment: I have already tried https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2, getting an error on that, the tool is still under development

Comment: A great tool for developer to run only one cron job

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add an update on this, I was able to use [n98-magerun2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2) to achieve my requirement, previously it was not working, recently I try it once again and it is now working, guess the issue got fixed :)

Comment: then accept @Manuel Garcia's answer as he advised you to do so earlier.

Comment: @JulienLachal the answer provided was for magento 1 not for magento 2

Comment: are you 100% sure the command isn't the same then?

Comment: @JulienLachal you are right the command is the same